# What is the value of ~x when the value of x is a boolean?

Tags: ruby

When `x = false`, the value of `~x` should be `true` (`~x == true`), right? But instead, I'm getting an error saying:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `~' for false:FalseClass
```

Why is this?

Comment: x doesn't have `~` method, maybe you can use `!`.

Comment: liuzxc is right. What you need is `!`, not `~`.

Comment: `~x=true` is syntactically wrong. `~x` is not a variable. It does not make sense.

Comment: You're confusing the [bitwise not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#NOT) `~` with the [logical not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation) `!`.

Answer (score 2):

x doesn't have `~` method, you should use `!`.

```
irb(main):001:0> x=false
=> false
irb(main):002:0> !x
=> true
irb(main):003:0> x.class
=> FalseClass
irb(main):004:0> FalseClass.instance_methods
=> [:to_s, :&, :|, :^, :nil?, :===, :=~, :!~, :eql?, :hash, :<=>, :class, :singleton_class, :clone, :dup, :initialize_dup, :initialize_clone, :taint, :tainted?, :untaint, :untrust, :untrusted?, :trust, :freeze, :frozen?, :inspect, :methods, :singleton_methods, :protected_methods, :private_methods, :public_methods, :instance_variables, :instance_variable_get, :instance_variable_set, :instance_variable_defined?, :instance_of?, :kind_of?, :is_a?, :tap, :send, :public_send, :respond_to?, :respond_to_missing?, :extend, :display, :method, :public_method, :define_singleton_method, :object_id, :to_enum, :enum_for, :==, :equal?, :!, :!=, :instance_eval, :instance_exec, :__send__, :__id__]
```

`instance_methods` can list all instance methods of current class.

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby, tilde `~` operator is available only for following classes:

- [Bignum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Bignum.html#method-i-7E)
- <del>[Complex](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Complex.html#method-i-7E)</del>
- [Fixnum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-7E)
- [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-i-7E)

Also in Ruby `true` belongs to `TrueClass` and `false` belongs to `FalseClass`. If you check their documentations here:

- [TrueClass](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/TrueClass.html), and
- [FalseClass](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/FalseClass.html)

You can see there is no `~` method listed. Since this method is not available for these class, you are getting the apt error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `~' for false:FalseClass

Comment: Although the documentation lists `Complex#~`, it is not actually available.

Comment: @Stefan is than an error in documentation?

Comment: Maybe a bug in RDoc.

Answer (score 0):

Booleans doesn't have `~` method. This method is presented in e.g. [numbers](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-7E)

For booleans you need `!`.

```
!x
```